# How to use preg_replace to unfold subject lines?

Tags: php, regex

[Please excuse all the code sequences, the only way to ensure backslashes aren't being escaped.]

We have an email server which is inserting LF + white-space in subject lines. These show up in the JSON as `"text\\\n  text"`. We'd like to join the lines together.

This code:

```
<?php
// The subject line is a property of an object, and
// must be decoded to extract it so we can work on it.
$x = json_decode('"abc\\\n  def"');
// Echo before and after
echo $x.PHP_EOL.preg_replace('/\\\\n\s+/', '', $x);
```

will output:

```
abc\n  def
abcdef
```

which is what we want, but when we're running it on actual data, we get:

```
abc\n  def
abc\\ def
```

So something isn't right. I wouldn't be surprised if the API is returning screwy JSON and while it is printing it as `"text\\\n  text"`, it's actually something else.

For example, regarding `"text\\\n  text"`, does the sequence `\\\n` make sense? `\\` means one backslash, and `\n` means the line feed, so shouldn't it be represented in the JSON as `\\n`?

If anyone can shed some light on this, would be much appreciated. Going crazy trying to fix this.

Note: After putting two and two together, I tried this in the actual running code to replace an escaped backslash and a raw LF followed by two spaces:

`echo preg_replace('/\\\\\n  /', '', $x);`

It seems to work okay in the code, but not in isolation! So it likely is screwy JSON being returned. I think what they're doing is terminating with a literal backslash (like a line continuation in C), then followed by a linefeed and two spaces. Not exactly the standard!

Comment: _You think what they're doing..._ Haven't you looked at the raw data to see what's being sent?

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't reporting it properly and I was expecting the standard MIME folding sequence. The JSON should have been displayed as `"abc\\␊  def"` to indicate an escaped backslash and an embedded LF. Probably not legal JSON. Now that I look back, I can see why standard JSON formatters were rejecting it. I guess PHP is more forgiving.